# How to construct a data dependence graph from Assembly code

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, llvm, code-analysis

I would like to know if there is any existing tools that can construct a data dependence graph, starting from an assembly piece of code?

My objective is: starting from a set of assembly instructions (resulting from compiled C code using GCC/LLVM), construct a dependence graph, that would help analyze how each variable contributes to the final result.

Any suggestions of what I could learn about in order to achieve this? Can existing compilers output something like that or an intermediate representation that I can transform graphically?

E.g. if we consider a simple addition `D = (A + B)*C`, such as the following :

```
load R1, Address_of_A
load R2, Address_of_B
load R3, Address_of_C
add  R4, R1, R2
mul  R5, R4, R3  
store R5, Address_of_D
```

The result could be something like:

```
A ----
      (+)------
B ----         |--------
                       (*)----> D
C ----------------------
```

Comment: I think you'll enjoy reading about [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form), even if that isn't an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous tools for this on Github. I suggest looking at [miasm](https://github.com/cea-sec/miasm), the code is in Python and is extremely readable. Dataflow construction is in [data_flow.py](https://github.com/cea-sec/miasm/blob/master/miasm/analysis/data_flow.py).